# how to call recent post content in a loop ( only the content before read more tag)

Tags: posts, loop

i try to call the content of the recenet posts, not all the content, only the content before 'read more' tag. but it repeats the content of the lastest post. 
i want to creat one slider with 5 recent posts with post image and short post conent. Can someone please help me !!!!
here is my code:

```
<ul class="slides">
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
       echo '<li>';
       $content = get_the_content('Read more');
       print $content;
       echo '</li> ';
                }
       wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```

[image]

Comment: get_the_content uses the global $post, not $recent

Answer (score 0):

for latest 5 post you can use this code:

```
$args = array('post_type'=>'post', 'posts_per_page'=> 5);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if($query->have_posts()):
    while($query->have_posts()):$query->the_post();
       echo '<li>';
       $content = get_the_excerpt();
```

//for featured image

```
if(has_post_thumbnail()):
the_post_thumbnail();
endif;
           print $content;
           echo '</li> ';
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
```

In case you want to change word count in excerpt use this action hook function. 
    /**
     * Filter the except length to 20 words.
     *
     * @param int $length Excerpt length.
     * @return int (Maybe) modified excerpt length.
     */

```
   function wpdocs_custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
        return 20;
    }
    add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'wpdocs_custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

In case you need to change read more text.

/**
 * Filter the "read more" excerpt string link to the post.
 *
 * @param string $more "Read more" excerpt string.
 * @return string (Maybe) modified "read more" excerpt string.
 */

```
function wpdocs_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return sprintf( '<a class="read-more" href="%1$s">%2$s</a>',
        get_permalink( get_the_ID() ),
        __( 'Read More', 'textdomain' )
    );
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'wpdocs_excerpt_more' );
```

hope this will help!